# How to specify the area of a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have an area (say User). I return a PartialView from an action method through an Ajax call as below.

```
return PartialView("_Users");
```

But at this time mvc searches the general shared folder and general user folder. It is not searching inside the area for the partial view. And thus I am getting an error. :(

How can I specify that this partial view resides under an area, at the time it returns from a view?

Answer (score 4):

If you are not calling this action outside of the area, it won't search there. Let's say your partial view inside the following folder:

> ~/Areas/User/Views/Shared/_Users.cshtml

And assume that you are calling this partial view inside `Bar` action of `Poo` controller in your `User` area, the search order will be this one:

> ~/Areas/User/Views/Poo/_Users.cshtml
>
> ~/Areas/User/Views/Shared/_Users.cshtml
>
> ~/Views/Shared/_Users.cshtml

If you call this partial view out side of the Area, it will still look for the following folder and the related folder according to your controller and area (if there is one):

> ~/Views/Shared/_Users.cshtml

but not inside the `User` area.

It seems that you partial view is an application wide partial view. My advice is to move it to the following folder:

> ~/Views/Shared/